# Rails 4 has_many association twice in the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration, associations

Here is some info on my current problem:

I have two models, User and Activity. An User can create Activities and also bookmark them.

I currently have a working setup that allows an User to create Activities and I'm looking to modify it to also be able to bookmark them but with no success.

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :activities
  ...
end
```

activity.rb

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
 ...
 belongs_to :user
 ...
end
```

Can I do something like this?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :activities
 has_many :bookmarks, :through => :activities
end
```

Is a many_to_many with an 'inbetween' model a more appropriate approach?

Regarding the above approach, when I try to retrieve an User's bookmarks, this is what I get:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError (Could not find the source association(s) "bookmark" or :bookmarks in model Activity.
```

Comment: Could you describe more? What happened, any error message?

Comment: Yes, for example, when I approach the problem using the above method and I try to retrieve the user's bookmarks, I get this error:

"ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError (Could not find the source association(s) "bookmark" or :book
marks in model Activity. Try 'has_many :bookmarks, :through => :activities, :source => <name>'."

Thank you for your reply

Comment: How about the current schema, Does `Activity` has many `bookmarks`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes you can do**

In your `/app/models/activity.rb` file add `belongs_to :bookmark` and you can add `belongs_to :user` if you want to use `has_many :users, through: :activities` to `bookmarks.rb`.

**If you don't have bookmark model**

Many to many relationship requires a table which can be used to join two models. Here User and Activity are two models and to make many to many relationship there must exists another table between then so that they can be related. Here to connect these two tables you can make and use user_activity table or bookmarks table and a model associated with this table.

After that you can use the approach you are following.
Enjoy

Comment: That is one way to approach it. I was trying to do everything without having a Bookmark model. Any suggestions? Or should I stick to this solution?

Answer (score 0):

The way I was trying to do things is not valid and it doesn't work. Like [Pradeep Sapkota](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4209704/pradeep-sapkota) hinted, the solution for this kind of problem is very simple and is as follows:

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :activities
 has_many :bookmarks
end
```

Bookmark.rb (new file)

```
class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :activity
end
```

Activity.rb

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user  
 has_many :bookmarks
end
```

We also need to create a new migration to add the Bookmarks table

```
class CreateBookmarks < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :bookmarks do |t|
   t.belongs_to :user, index: true
   t.belongs_to :activity, index: true

   t.timestamps
  end
 end
end
```